# Determining independent events

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Two dices are thrown.

$F_{e}$ = the event that the first die is even

$S_{4}$ = the event that the second die is 4

$\Sigma_{o}$ = the sum of the two dice is odd

Which of the events [1-4] are independent?

1. $F_{e}$ and $S_{4}$
2. $F_{e}$ and $\Sigma_{o}$
3. $S_{4}$ and $\Sigma_{o}$
4. $S_{4}$, $\Sigma_{o}$ and $F_{e}$ are mutually independent

Soliciting help to clarify my understanding.

$P(F_{e}) = \frac{1}{2}, P(S_{4}) = \frac{1}{6} and P(\Sigma_{o}) = \frac{1}{2}$

$P(F_{e} \cap S_{4}) = \frac{3}{36} = \frac{1}{12} = P(F_{e}) * P(S_{4})$ Hence independent

$P(F_{e} \cap \Sigma_{o}) = \frac{9}{36} = \frac{1}{4} = P(F_{e}) * P(\Sigma_{o})$ Hence independent

$P(\Sigma_{o} \cap S_{4}) = \frac{3}{36} = \frac{1}{12} = P(\Sigma_{o}) * P(S_{4})$ hence independent

[4] they are not mutually independent as

$P(\Sigma_{o} \cap S_{4} \cap F_{e}) \ne P(\Sigma_{o}) * P(S_{4}) * P(F_{e})$

- Did I do it correctly?
- Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: For what it's worth, I responded with an answer, and then deleted my answer, following your question's editing.  Your editing made my answer trivial.  One shortcut for question (4): if $F_e$ and $S_4$ both occur, then $\Sigma_{o}$ can not occur.  This alone disproves mutual independence.

Comment: Apologies for the quick edit as I initially identified the [4] as mutually independent but looking through several websites, I figured out that mutual independence condition is more stringent - any subset of events needs to follow the product rule. Hence the edit.

Comment: @user3138594 I agree  to your solution.